# Debugging with the right number of command-line arguments

Tags: python, cs50

I want to debug my code that check for a certain number of command-line arguments; but when I hit step over it goes straight to another condition where the command line arguments are fewer. How do I debug my code when I have the right number of command-line argument?

Here is the code that I am trying to debug

```
import sys
import csv

# check for two command-line arguments
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    try:
    # creat a buffer csv file
        buffer = []
        #open input file for reading
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
            # read input file
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                # append each line into a csv buffer
                buffer.append(row)

        # open output file for writing
        with open(sys.argv[2], "w") as file_output:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, fieldnames= ["first", "last", "house"])
            # ignore the first row of csv buffer
            for line in buffer[1:]:
                # split contents of csv buffer
                line[0] = "first"
                line[1] = "last"
                line[2] = "house"
                # write into the output file
                writer.writerow({"first": first, "last": last, "house": house})

    except OSError:
        sys.exit(f"Couldn't read {sys.argv[1]}")




# check for fewer command-line arguments
elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.exit("Too few comman-line arguments")

# check for more command-line argument
else:
    sys.exit("Too many command-line arguments")
```

My code is not working as I expected; I am trying to debug it.

Comment: With what command are you running this script, from where in your file system are running that command and what does the file tree look like? You can easily inspect the incoming arguments by `print(sys.argv)`

Comment: I am doing problem set6 of cs50p https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/6/scourgify/. The commands are in the problem set's instructions

Comment: That's not really an answer to my questions.

Comment: As DSteman said, add `print(sys.argv)` to help debug and check which arguments are actually being passed in when your code is being run.

Comment: Use Step In, not Step Over.  That being said, instead of having your main program inside the `if` block it would be better to have an if/else guard clause at the start of the program that quits if the wrong number of arguments were entered, and if the correct number were entered you can just proceed into the main code.